# apache server closed when i run my program in using of imagick

Tags: php, apache, imagick

i installed imagick library and download dll file from

> http://valokuva.org/outside-blog-content/imagick-windows-builds/php53/imagick-2.3.0-dev/vc9_zts/php_imagick.dll

and copy to wamp/bin/php/php5.3/ext/php_imagick.dll  and i see this message from wamp after add this line to php.ini :

> extension=php_imagick.dll

wamp messege:

> module 'imagick' already loaded

and in phpinfo() there are imagick table.

but when i run this php code that come in below:

```
$image = new Imagick("./s/Page_ (1).jpg");
$image->cropImage(2242,3090, 120,210);
$flag = $image->writeImage("./c/Page_ (1).jpg");
 if($flag){
    echo "true ";
 }else{
    echo "false ";
 }
```

but i have not any response and after some loading i see this error from windows:

> Apache HTTP Server has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We
>   are sorry for the inconvenience.

and in "./c/Page_ (1).jpg" is not any cropped picture!

notice: "./s/Page_ (1).jpg" is a jpeg file in size: 2482x3510

please help me :(

Comment: Look in Apache's error logs why exactly it is crashing.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Tue Jul 09 01:03:03 2013] [notice] Child 1900: Child process is running

Comment: Child 1900: Acquired the start mutex.

Comment: So do you have the imagick module in there twice? There must be a reason for this happening. Is it already loaded somewhere in php.ini?

Comment: oh i add this extension twice in php.ini, ok but apache crashed again.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you removed the second entry?

Comment: yes i do :( but it crashed

Comment: And what is the error message in Apache now?

Comment: [Tue Jul 09 02:07:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:31 2013] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:31 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2964
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:33 2013] [notice] Child 2964: Child process is running
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:33 2013] [notice] Child 2964: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:33 2013] [notice] Child 2964: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jul 09 02:07:33 2013] [notice] Child 2964: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

Comment: Is that the error log? That would be strange, as there is no trace of a crash there

Comment: but i recived every time this error from windows: Apache HTTP Server has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: i use from GD extension! this problem is not necessory..